# I need an API key for a personal site, but was given one in conjunction with my company page

Tags: api, facebook-comments

I want to be sure that if I use the api key for my personal blog, that it won't connect to my company page in any way.

Can I be sure of this? I got an API, but it says it's connected to the company page I help manage.

Thanks...

Matt

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new application for your website by visiting this link http://www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php and clicking the "+ Create New App" button on the top right.

If it mentions your company's Page, it's probably not the one you should be using for your personal site.